# Smart contract creation

Tags: erc-20, tokens, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I just joined because I am trying to learn how to create Solidity contracts using OpenZepplin.

I am using also claude AI to guide me but it has a limit and it's going in circles now.

Until now I managed to create the following:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Compatible with OpenZeppelin Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol";

contract TestToken is ERC20Burnable, ERC20Permit, ERC20Capped {
    address payable public owner;

    constructor(uint256 cap) ERC20("TestToken", "TTO") ERC20Permit("TestToken") ERC20Capped(cap * (10 ** decimals())) {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        _mint(owner, 100000000 * (10 ** decimals())); // 100 mil
    }

    //Override update function due to compilation errors
    function _update(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount
    ) internal virtual override(ERC20, ERC20Capped) {
        super._update(_from, _to, _amount); // Call ERC20's _update
        if (_from == address(0)) {
            require(totalSupply() + _amount <= cap(), "ERC20Capped: cap exceeded");
        }
    }
}
```

But I am unsure about a few aspects and I would like more expert developers to point me in the right direction.

The token I am trying to create should be:

- Mint 100 million tokens on deploy
- Burnable
- When I deploy it it should send to the test wallet the full amount of tokens
- The cap is 100 millions

I think all the extensions I added from OpenZeppelin take care of the above aspects. But what about security?

Is that it? Or should I add methods to prevent hacking that I am not aware about?

Also for the tests, I was trying to build some, but I am not about what to test sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using Openzeppelin then no need to worry about security as their contracts are highly secured and widely used. You can review the contracts though.
You don't add methods to prevent hacking.

For writing tests, you can use JS with hardhat or you can also test in solidity itself, using foundry.

Writing tests is all about thinking like a hacker, who wants to break the code. Think of different scenarios and then write a test for that.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/Zartaj0/MultiSigWallet/blob/main/test/MultiSIg.js)  of a JS test file.

Comment: Understood. I was thinking other code was needed. Thanks :)

Comment: If you have any suggestion on how to improve the test token or if I am missing anything, I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Dev Advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

OpenZeppelin does a great job making secure contracts, which are usually up to the latest security standards.

If it looks like there is very little code in your contract, it is because the bulk of the logic is abstracted into the files you import at the top.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol";
```

You can find them and review them in the [OpenZeppelin GitHub repository](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20).

Comment: That is amazing. Anyway I was reading also about adding a function to avoid whales? Because when you list then you risk to be bought off. I wonder if the ERC20Permit has this already implemented or not.